# Geolocator requesting location permissions after throwing "User denied permissions to access the device's location."

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, geolocator

I am attempting to fix a mobile/web application that someone else built. I am pretty new to using Flutter and Geolocator.

The app is designed such that after pressing the "Activate Warranty" button, the user is prompted to give the app access to the device's location, then the user can input the necessary information for activating their warranty.

The actual behaviour after pressing this button - while running the application in Debug mode with Android Studio (testing on an external iOS device) - is several errors thrown within AS's debugger, listed in order by pressing Resume Program after each error:

```
GeolocatorApple.getCurrentPosition (geolocator_apple.dart:127)
```

```
exception = {PermissionDeniedException} User denied permissions to access the device's location.
```

"Resume Program" is pressed

```
Error._throw (errors_patch.dart:27)
Error.throwWithStackTrace (errors.dart:120)
_rootHandleError.<anonymous closure> (zone.dart:1386)
_microtaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:40)
_startMicrotaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:49)
```

```
exception = {PermissionDeniedException} User denied permissions to access the device's location.
error = {PermissionDeniedException} User denied permissions to access the device's location.
stackTrace = {_StackTrace}
```

StackTrace:

```
#0      GeolocatorApple.getCurrentPosition 
(package:geolocator_apple/src/geolocator_apple.dart:127:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

"Resume Program" is pressed

```
_startMicrotaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:1)
```

```
exception = {PermissionDeniedException} User denied permissions to access the device's location.
```

"Resume Program" is pressed

App prompts user to allow application to use device's location, and works as expected.

---

In activate_warranty.dart:

```dart
class _ActivateWarrantyState extends State<ActivateWarranty> {
  final GeolocatorPlatform _geolocatorPlatform = GeolocatorPlatform.instance;

   var geolocator = Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(forceAndroidLocationManager: true);
   var _currentPosition;
   late List<Placemark> p;
   double lat = 0.0, long = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _currentPosition = _getCurrentLocation();
    super.initState();
  }

Future<Position> _getCurrentLocation() async {
    LocationPermission permission;

    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();

    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      return Future.error('Location services are not enabled.');
    }

    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error('Location permissions are  denied.');
      }
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error('Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
    }

    Position position = await _geolocatorPlatform.getCurrentPosition();
    this.lat = position.latitude;
    this.long = position.longitude;

    return position;
  }
}
```

I have tried every variation to this that I can think of or find online in both the Geolocator documentation, and Stack Overflow, but I have had no luck.

My next potential solution that I will attempt is to try putting the entire _getCurrentLocation() method in a different location (before leaving the previous page of the application, right before submitting the warranty activation request, or perhaps as early as right after login), but I was wondering if I have missed something that is causing the error checking to be run before the actual location permission request.

Comment: Update: I moved the location permission request to the previous screen and it seems to be working. Still not sure why the error checking ran before the request, so I'll leave this up, in case anyone has insight. Feel free to close this